# why the \tl_gset:Nn or .tl_gset:N not work when token list out of \keys_define:nn?

Tags: latex3, l3keys

I want to write my own package, when I use my package, I want to give some paper size option. but whatever I try, `\g__zztj_paper_size_tl` is invalid when out of `\key_define:nn`. the MWE is:

```
% sty file
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{zztj}{}{}{}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

\tl_new:N \g__zztj_paper_size_tl 

% ---- \keys_define:nn ---- one ----
\keys_define:nn { zztj / option }
  {
    paper .choices:nn = 
    { a4, a5 }
    { \tl_gset:Nn \g__zztj_paper_size_tl {#1} } ,
    paper  .default:n = { a4 }
  }

% \tl_show:N \g__zztj_paper_size_tl % <-- \g__zztj_paper_size_tl is empty

\tl_if_eq:NnT \g__zztj_paper_size_tl { a4 }
  { \newcommand\foo{foo~a4\par}}
\tl_if_eq:NnT \g__zztj_paper_size_tl { a5 }
  { \newcommand\foo{foo~a5\par}}

% there are some other codes ... so I can't just write all commands in \keys_define:nn

\tl_if_eq:NnT \g__zztj_paper_size_tl { a4 }
  { \newcommand\bar{bar~a4\par}}
\tl_if_eq:NnT \g__zztj_paper_size_tl { a5 }
  { \newcommand\bar{bar~a5\par}}

\ProcessKeysOptions{ zztj / option }


% tex file
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paper=a4]{zztj}

\begin{document}
  \foo
  \bar
\end{document}
```

I also try another way `\keys_define:nn`:

```
% ---- \keys_define:nn ---- another ----
\keys_define:nn { zztj / option }
  {
    paper   .tl_gset:N = \g__zztj_paper_size_tl ,
  }
```

but both of them can't work. I use the `expl3` package released on `2021-02-18`. anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: You've not set any keys at the point you test `\g__zztj_paper_size_tl`, so it's empty and none of your command creation occurs. Did you mix up `.defaut:n` and `.initial:n`? The latter is the same as setting the key, whereas `.default:n` is about what happens if you give the key name but no value.

Comment: Thank you. I understand `.defaut:n` and `.initial:n`. You can ignore the `.defaut:n` code. 
So you mean the load package behavior is, 
1) load the package, then test `\g__zztj_paper_size_tl`, so the `\g__zztj_paper_size_tl` is empty, 
2) then option pass to package? But `\g__zztj_paper_size_tl` is test, so I fail.
Am I right? 
Then can I change this behavior? My idea is, I don't want to `\g__zztj_paper_size_tl` to be test immediately when the package load, until the option pass to my package. Or I want to option pass to my package firstly then test the `\g__zztj_paper_size_tl`.

Comment: You choose where in the code to put `\ProcesssKeysOptions`: you can just move it before the various tests. Am I missing something about your code order?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, the problem is in `\ProcesssKeysOptions`, I put it in the end of file, so the test fail. When I put before the test, the test now successful. But another problem comming: I want to use `\newcommand` in my code, but TeX complain `! LaTeX Error: Command \bar already defined.` in `l.31   { \newcommand\bar{bar~a4\par}}`, why the `\bar` is already defined?

Comment: OMG, the problem is latex already defined `\bar`...

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
    paper  .initial:n = { a4 }
```

not `.default:n`. With `.default:n` you specify the value to be assigned if the key is called without values.

Look at the difference:

```
\keys_define:nn { test }
 {
  foo .tl_set:N = \l_test_foo_tl,
  foo .default:n = footest,
  bar .tl_set:N = \l_test_bar_tl,
  bar .initial:n = bartest,
 }

\tl_show:N \l_test_foo_tl % empty
\tl_show:N \l_test_bar_tl % contains 'bartest'

\keys_set:nn { test } { foo }

\tl_show:N \l_test_foo_tl % contains 'footest'

\keys_set:nn { test } { foo=newtest }

\tl_show:N \l_test_foo_tl % contains 'newtest'
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand `.defaut:n` and `.initial:n`. But my idea is, I don't want to `\g__zztj_paper_size_tl` to be test immediately when the package load, until the option pass to my package. Or I want to option pass to my package firstly then test the `\g__zztj_paper_size_tl`. Can I do it?

Comment: @redmoon You can set no initial value and test whether the token list is still empty after `\ProcessKeyOptions`

Comment: Yes, it's the `\ProcessKeyOptions` order's problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `\ProcessKeysOptions` order. If put the `\ProcessKeysOptions` before test, the test is successful. BTW, don't use `\bar` in `\newcommand`, it's already defined in LaTeX. Post the successful MWE:

```
% sty file
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{zztj}{}{}{}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

\tl_new:N \g__zztj_paper_size_tl 

\keys_define:nn { zztj / option }
  {
    paper .choices:nn = 
    { a4, a5 }
    { \tl_gset:Nn \g__zztj_paper_size_tl {#1} } ,
    paper  .default:n = { a4 }
  }

\ProcessKeysOptions{ zztj / option }

\tl_if_eq:NnT \g__zztj_paper_size_tl { a4 }
  { \newcommand\zztjfoo{foo~a4\par}}
\tl_if_eq:NnT \g__zztj_paper_size_tl { a5 }
  { \newcommand\zztjfoo{foo~a5\par}}

% other codes ...

\tl_if_eq:NnT \g__zztj_paper_size_tl { a4 }
  { \newcommand\zztjbar{bar~a4\par}}
\tl_if_eq:NnT \g__zztj_paper_size_tl { a5 }
  { \newcommand\zztjbar{bar~a5\par}}


% tex file
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paper=a4]{zztj}

\begin{document}
  \zztjfoo
  \zztjbar
\end{document}
```